# is there a better option to work with other than time.sleep() in tkinter GUI

Tags: tkinter, sleep, tkinter-button

Guys everytime I use time.sleep() my program misbehaves and I needed to delay my program for a few seconds before proceeding what can I do

I imported time and my program started to hang I cant even click on the button when I used window.sleep
I was creating a bank program and I wanted to change the color of the display text to red when someone tries to withdraw an amount that is greater than the balance then the program should sleep for a few seconds then turn the text back to green.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `after` method, which schedules code to be run in the future.

In the following example, when you click the button the text will turn red, then 5 seconds (5000 milliseconds) later it will turn green.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Example:
    def __init__(self):
        root = tk.Tk()
        self.button = tk.Button(root, text="Click me", command=self.do_click)
        self.label = tk.Label(root, text="Hello, world")
        self.button.pack(side="left")
        self.label.pack(side="left", fill="x")

    def do_click(self):
        def turn_it_green():
            self.label.configure(foreground="green")
            
        self.label.configure(foreground="red")
        self.label.after(5000, turn_it_green)

e = Example()
tk.mainloop()
```